# Is there a way for not including jars in a generated WAR while also including the version in the pom on META-INF?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, war

The projects I work with consist of a main module and 4 other modules, each with their pom

- Main
- B
- C
- D
- Web

The main module has all of the dependencies listed in its POM within DependencyManagement, along with the version.
The rest include only the library within Dependencies on their POM **without** the version number.

The web module is the one that we export as a WAR, which when generated includes its POM within the META-INF.

**Scenario 1**

Is there a way to generate a WAR file that doesn't include all of the jars except for the ones corresponding to the other modules?

I've seen some solutions that speak of adding a Maven EAR definition but that it is a painstaking process and doesn't overall result in a smaller project file anyway.

**Scenario 2**

Otherwise, if there is no such way to achieve that through the POM, is there a way to at least have the version numbers included in the main module to be reflected onto the WAR's META-INF pom?

In this other scenario at least I could delete the jar files via a script and then run a copy-dependencies maven command on the target computer, not spending extra time on sending over jar files that might otherwise be over there.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent unwanted jars from being included in final WAR file by changing their scope to provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```